# Power BI - Matrix count of values in query

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to create a matrix table that will count the number of jobs due in a month and also if they are completed on time.

At present I can get it this far.
[image]

I have tried summarizing data, creating measures etc. But to no avail.

I need to produce the following:

[image: Desired output]

My data source is a series of transactions lines that include

1) Transaction Due date
2) Transaction completed date

Definition of terms:

```
Due in month        Count of due date
Done on time        Completed within due month
Outside time        completed outside due month
"%Perf"             percentage completed on time.
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: It will be helpful if you provide an image of your data model. DAX depends on data structures and their relations.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, all the information comes from a single table with the following relevant fields: [job_id]- Unique, [due_date], [completed], due date format DD/MM/YYYY, completed DD/MM/YYY hh:mm

Comment: Can you please include 20 rows of data so we understand what you talk about. Also, what does Incomplete mean?

Comment: The general premise is a job is booked in for a particular month, if it is completed within the due month it is considered "Done on time", if it is completed in any subsequent month it is "Outside time".  If there is no completed date then it would be considered "Incomplete".  I hope this helps to clarify my issue. - Data image added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following measures:

**Measure "Due":**

```
Due = COUNTROWS ( Table1 )
```

**Measure "Done on time":**

```
Done on time = 
VAR DueMonth = MONTH ( FIRSTDATE ( Table1[due_date] ) )
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( 
        [Due],
        FILTER ( 
            Table1,
            MONTH ( Table1[completed] ) = DueMonth
        )
    )
```

**Measure "Outside time":**

```
Outside time = 
VAR DueMonth = MONTH ( FIRSTDATE ( Table1[due_date] ) )
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( 
        [Due],
        FILTER ( 
            Table1,
            MONTH ( Table1[completed] ) <> DueMonth && 
            NOT ISBLANK ( Table1[completed] )
        )
    )
```

**Measure "Incomplete":**

```
Incomplete = 
VAR DueMonth = MONTH ( FIRSTDATE ( Table1[due_date] ) )
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( 
        [Due],
        FILTER ( 
            Table1,
            ISBLANK ( Table1[completed] )
        )
    )
```

**Measure "% Perf"**

```
% Perf = 
    DIVIDE ( 
        [Done on time],
        [Due],
        BLANK()
    )
```

Group by `due_date.month` in report.

See https://pwrbi.com/so_55513978/ for worked example PBIX file.

### EDIT after updated question in comment:

There are many ways you could approach creating a visualisation which combines these measures, with the monthly counts by completion date, if you really must. Here's one approach:

**Create a "Report Columns" table:**

```
Report Columns = 
VAR ListMeasures = 
    DATATABLE ( 
        "Header", STRING,
        "Sort Order", INTEGER,
        "First Of Month", DATETIME,
        { 
            {"Due in month", 1, BLANK() }, 
            {"Done on time", 2, BLANK() }, 
            {"Outside time", 3, BLANK() }, 
            {"Incomplete", 4, BLANK() }, 
            {"% Perf", 5, BLANK() }
        }
    )
VAR ListMonths = 
    CALCULATETABLE(
        GROUPBY ( 
            ADDCOLUMNS ( 
                DISTINCT ( Table1[completed] ),
                "Header", FORMAT ( Table1[completed], "YYYY-MMM" ),
                "Sort Order", YEAR ( Table1[completed] ) * 100 + MONTH ( Table1[completed] ),
                "First Of Month", DATE ( YEAR ( Table1[completed] ), MONTH ( Table1[completed] ), 1 )
            ),
            [Header], [Sort Order], [First Of Month]
        ),
        Table1[completed] <> BLANK()
    )
RETURN 
    UNION ( 
        ListMeasures, 
        ListMonths 
    )
```

Set column `Header` to Sort By column `Sort Order`

**Create Measure "Report Measure":**

```
Report Measure = 
IF ( 
    NOT HASONEFILTER ( 'Report Columns'[Header] ), 
    BLANK(),
    SWITCH ( 
        VALUES ( 'Report Columns'[Header] ),
        "Due in month", [Due],
        "Done on time", [Done on time],
        "Outside time", [Outside time],
        "Incomplete", [Incomplete],
        "% Perf", [% Perf],
        CALCULATE ( 
            [Due],
            FILTER ( 
                Table1,
                DATE ( YEAR ( Table1[completed] ), MONTH ( Table1[completed] ), 1 ) = VALUES ( 'Report Columns'[First Of Month] )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Add a matrix visualisation, with `Table1[due_date]` in rows, `Report Columns[Header]` in Columns, and `[Report Measure]` in values. Format to suit.

[image]

Updated example PBIX file: https://pwrbi.com/so_55513978-2/

Comment: Thanks Olly, I will try that when I get back in front of my computer, I will let you know how I get on.

Comment: Fantastic that looks like it will do the trick, I assume then to create the April, May Columns in the list I would need to create another measure for each month that would count the completed dates and apply to that column?

Comment: Can anyone help with the Monthly column totals?

Comment: Olly you are a star, looks pretty good, just one question can you clarify the Group by due_date.month in report.  If I group by this in the query editor it would create a new column or am I picking you up wrong.  Thanks again.

Comment: I simply mean put field `due_date.month` in the rows section of the Matrix visualisation, as in the example PBIX file.

Comment: Sorry, picked you up completely wrong there lol.  Will try your solution when back at my desk, thanks for taking the time to help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: That made more sense and works, there is just one last question I have to put this all to bed.  I have indexed information in the past using a separate table of information, but there has always been a relationship defined between them so as to allow selection of the other indexing field.  I am not seeing a relationship in your example, but your file works regardless and uses the sort order specified in the "Report Columns" table.

Comment: No relationship is appropriate or required, here - the additional table only provides the report headers, then the measure references the header value.